# Non-Parametric ANOVA: Repeated Measures with Replication

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, nonparametric, friedman-test

I'm struggling to find out which ANOVA test to use when you have a non-normal data set with repeated measures AND replication.

I'm doing my data analysis in R and the Friedman test `friedman.test()` method says it is only suitable for un-replicated data. Is there a way I can twist my data to fit the test?

To be specific:
I have put each subject through 4 different treatments (repeated measure) three times each (replication). I want to look for significant differences between the treatments.  My empty data table is structured like this:

```
SubjectID | Treatment1 | Treatment2 | Treatment3 | Treatment4 <br>
1 
1 
1 
2 
2 
2
```

etc....

Any pointers to the right test would be really appriciated!